# How to add columns to a pandas Dataframe that has row filled with range based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I created a df and then repeated rows in that df based on values in a column. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [1,2,3],
        'b': ['x','y','z']
        })
```

Then I repeated the rows based on a col value like this:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['a'])]
```

and I got:

```
df
Out[150]: 
   a  b
0  1  x
1  2  y
1  2  y
2  3  z
2  3  z
2  3  z
```

Now I want to add another column with values having increment count based on a  column values (in this case values from column a),
The desired output is:

```
df
Out[150]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  x  1
1  2  y  1
1  2  y  2
2  3  z  1
2  3  z  2
2  3  z  3
```

How can I do this. Range function doesn't work in a vectorized fashion, so I need help. Thanks.

Comment: FYI.... In this example, I think `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['a']))` is faster than `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['a'])]`

Comment: Thanks I will use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use[`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by values of index and then create default `index` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['a'])]   
df['c'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  x  1
1  2  y  1
2  2  y  2
3  3  z  1
4  3  z  2
5  3  z  3
```

Comment: Great answer @jezrael..Thanks